# Why isn't gunicorn working with my Flask app?

Tags: python, gunicorn, eventlet

I have a simple Flask app set up which runs with the command `flask run`. I'd like to be able to run this app in a Docker container, which I'm trying to do using a gunicorn server. However, when I try to run using gunicorn I'm seeing error messages. I'm running `gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app` which I got from their [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#gunicorn-web-server)

I have a simple flask-socketio app:

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Here's the contents of app.py:

```
import os
import sys
from eventlet import patcher, support
import six
select = patcher.original('select')
time = patcher.original('time')

from eventlet.hubs.hub import BaseHub, READ, WRITE, noop


if getattr(select, 'kqueue', None) is None:
    raise ImportError('No kqueue implementation found in select module')


FILTERS = {READ: select.KQ_FILTER_READ,
           WRITE: select.KQ_FILTER_WRITE}


class Hub(BaseHub):
    MAX_EVENTS = 100

    def __init__(self, clock=None):
        super(Hub, self).__init__(clock)
        self._events = {}
        self._init_kqueue()

    def _init_kqueue(self):
        self.kqueue = select.kqueue()
        self._pid = os.getpid()

    def _reinit_kqueue(self):
        self.kqueue.close()
        self._init_kqueue()
        kqueue = self.kqueue
        events = [e for i in six.itervalues(self._events)
                  for e in six.itervalues(i)]
        kqueue.control(events, 0, 0)

    def _control(self, events, max_events, timeout):
        try:
            return self.kqueue.control(events, max_events, timeout)
        except (OSError, IOError):
            # have we forked?
            if os.getpid() != self._pid:
                self._reinit_kqueue()
                return self.kqueue.control(events, max_events, timeout)
            raise

    def add(self, evtype, fileno, cb, tb, mac):
        listener = super(Hub, self).add(evtype, fileno, cb, tb, mac)
        events = self._events.setdefault(fileno, {})
        if evtype not in events:
            try:
                event = select.kevent(fileno, FILTERS.get(evtype), select.KQ_EV_ADD)
                self._control([event], 0, 0)
                events[evtype] = event
            except ValueError:
                super(Hub, self).remove(listener)
                raise
        return listener

    def _delete_events(self, events):
        del_events = [
            select.kevent(e.ident, e.filter, select.KQ_EV_DELETE)
            for e in events
        ]
        self._control(del_events, 0, 0)

    def remove(self, listener):
        super(Hub, self).remove(listener)
        evtype = listener.evtype
        fileno = listener.fileno
        if not self.listeners[evtype].get(fileno):
            event = self._events[fileno].pop(evtype, None)
            if event is None:
                return
            try:
                self._delete_events((event,))
            except OSError:
                pass

    def remove_descriptor(self, fileno):
        super(Hub, self).remove_descriptor(fileno)
        try:
            events = self._events.pop(fileno).values()
            self._delete_events(events)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        except OSError:
            pass

    def wait(self, seconds=None):
        readers = self.listeners[READ]
        writers = self.listeners[WRITE]

        if not readers and not writers:
            if seconds:
                time.sleep(seconds)
            return
        result = self._control([], self.MAX_EVENTS, seconds)
        SYSTEM_EXCEPTIONS = self.SYSTEM_EXCEPTIONS
        for event in result:
            fileno = event.ident
            evfilt = event.filter
            try:
                if evfilt == FILTERS[READ]:
                    readers.get(fileno, noop).cb(fileno)
                if evfilt == FILTERS[WRITE]:
                    writers.get(fileno, noop).cb(fileno)
            except SYSTEM_EXCEPTIONS:
                raise
            except:
                self.squelch_exception(fileno, sys.exc_info())
                support.clear_sys_exc_info()
```

Here are the errors I'm seeing when running the gunicorn command:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _after_fork at 0x1121fc1f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1510, in _after_fork
    thread._reset_internal_locks(True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 845, in _reset_internal_locks
    self._started._at_fork_reinit()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 527, in _at_fork_reinit
    self._cond._at_fork_reinit()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 253, in _at_fork_reinit
    self._lock._at_fork_reinit()
AttributeError: 'Semaphore' object has no attribute '_at_fork_reinit'
[2022-01-31 20:57:29 +0000] [51963] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 51963
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 460, in fire_timers
    timer()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 59, in __call__
    cb(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 219, in main
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 78, in _eventlet_serve
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 228, in accept
    self._trampoline(fd, read=True, timeout=self.gettimeout(), timeout_exc=_timeout_exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 206, in _trampoline
    return trampoline(fd, read=read, write=write, timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 160, in trampoline
    listener = hub.add(hub.READ, fileno, current.switch, current.throw, mark_as_closed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 55, in add
    self._control([event], 0, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 41, in _control
    return self.kqueue.control(events, max_events, timeout)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
[2022-01-31 20:57:29 +0000] [51963] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 134, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 166, in run
    eventlet.sleep(1.0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 36, in sleep
    hub.switch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 297, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 349, in run
    self.wait(sleep_time)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 100, in wait
    result = self._control([], self.MAX_EVENTS, seconds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 41, in _control
    return self.kqueue.control(events, max_events, timeout)
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong command or if there is some other issue preventing me from using gunicorn?

Comment: This may possibly be related: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/646

Comment: where is your Flask [`app`](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#initialization)? I can't see it inside `app` module (`app.py`)